# make a new PoS blockchain with geth (go-ethereum)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, new-blockchain

many tutorials out there tell how to create personal PoA or PoW chain with go-ethereum(geth), how to create a PoS based blockchain with go-ethereum ?

Answer (score -1):

Creating a new PoS blockchain with Geth (go-ethereum) is a relatively simple process. First, you will need to install Geth and create a new account. Once the account is created, you will need to initialize the blockchain with a genesis block. This will include setting the consensus algorithm to PoS and specifying the parameters for the network. After the genesis block is created, you will need to start the network by running Geth with the appropriate flags. Finally, you must create validators and miners to begin mining and validating blocks.

Comment: can u write code part in the answer please

Comment: This sounds like a GPT response